# Execute a command line without a process but with a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, process

Can I perform the following task with a thread instead of a process

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Eltima Software\\"
                + "USB to Ethernet Connector\\UsbService64.exe find-remote-devices " +      machineName);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `Thread` and a `Process` is, but the short answer is no.  You can execute the code within a `Thread` and process the results, but it will create another `Process`

Comment: does this mean ill have to write code in the exe again with java.. because i can just can not afford this to run in a process

Comment: Okay I completely have no idea what you're talking about now...

Comment: Short answer: You are trying to run a different _program_.  Different programs practically always run in different processes (i.e., different address spaces).